# How to select lines which have equal values in columns and mantain this characteristics

Tags: r, database, dataframe

I have a complete data frame of all cities from Brazil. I want just some predefined cities. I have a column with these predefined cities. Then I'd like to use all the columns from my data frame, but select only the lines which coincides the cities of column with all cities and the column with predefined cities.

```
data = read.csv(file="C:/Users/guilherme/Desktop/data.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
data
> AllCities Year1990 Year200 PredefinedCities CharacCities1 CharacCities2
1         A        2       4                C 12            5
2         B        2       2                A 11            10
3         C        3       4                F 09            2
4         D        4       2                 
5         E        5       6                 
6         F        6       2
```

I want the following

```
> data
  AllCities Year1990 Year200 PredefinedCities CharacCities1 CharacCities2
1         C        3       4                C 12            5
2         A        2       4                A 11            10
3         F        6       2                F 09            2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `merge` -

```
merge(
  data[, c("AllCities", "Year1990", "Year200")], 
  data[, c("PredefinedCities", "CharacCities1", "CharacCities2")],
  by.x = "AllCities", by.y = "PredefinedCities"
)

  AllCities Year1990 Year200 CharacCities1 CharacCities2
1         A        2       4            11            10
2         C        3       4            12             5
3         F        6       2             9             2
```

**Note** - Your data format is unusual. If you can, you should fix data source so that it gives you `AllCities` and `PreferredCities` tables separately or maybe even join them correctly before creating the csv file.

Data -

```
structure(list(AllCities = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), Year1990 = c(2L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), Year200 = c(4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 2L), PredefinedCities = c("C", 
"A", "F", "", "", ""), CharacCities1 = c(12L, 11L, 9L, NA, NA, 
NA), CharacCities2 = c(5L, 10L, 2L, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("AllCities", 
"Year1990", "Year200", "PredefinedCities", "CharacCities1", "CharacCities2"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data <- data[data$AllCities %in% data$PredefinedCities,]
```